# Line plot of two different grouped by dataframes

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have grouped data in 2 separate dataframes and want to plot them together with 2 separate lines in one plot.

I have grouped the data as I needed and plotted separate graphs based on the grouped data.

```
grouped_men = df_men.groupby('age').mean()[['oldpeak']]
grouped_women = df_women.groupby('age').mean()[['oldpeak']]
grouped_men.plot(kind='line',title='Mens age vs oldpeak')
grouped_women.plot(kind='line',title='Womens age vs oldpeak')
```

But now instead of 2 separate plots, i need to plot one single graph with 2 lines of both men and women.

Current plot look like this:
[image: plots]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify axes where Pandas should put the plots. Try the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
grouped_men.plot(kind='line', ax=ax, label='Mens age vs oldpeak')
grouped_women.plot(kind='line', ax=ax, label='Womens age vs oldpeak')
plt.gca().legend(title="Legend title")  # Changes
plt.show()
```

Comment: It works partially as in the legend in the upper right of the plot shows legend with 2 colors but the name is 'old peak' instead of 'Mens Age' and 'Womens Age'.

Comment: Try to specify legend's title:  `.legend(title='you title')`

Comment: Actually, it worked by giving .legend(['Mens Age', 'Womens Age'])